# AWS EB CLI - Exclude specific folders every time I run 'eb deploy'

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, ebcli

How to prevent specific folders from being replaced in every deployment? 
Consider the directory structure below:

```
-- /.ebextensions
-- /app
-- /database
-- /public
---- /css
---- /js
---- /images
```

I'm using AWS CodeCommit and EB CLI for my PHP application and every time I run `eb deploy` these files & directories are being replaced, so I want to exclude the `/public/images` directory so that the previous images that have been uploaded would still be there after a newer version has been deployed.

I've been digging on their documentation all week, but can't find any possible solution.Is this something possible with Elastic Beanstalk? Or any alternative suggestions for deployment in AWS will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `.ebignore` file and list all files and directories there.  If there is not `.ebignore` file it will use the `.gitignore` to exclude files from deployment.

I still do not think it will resolve the issue since the images folder will still be deleted.  I would suggest that you use S3 bucket and upload/get all images from there so you wont't have issues on deployment.

Please note that if you upload an image, when there are 3 ec2 at that time of image upload, the image will only be uploaded on one server unless you sync the ec2 on every upload. And this will result in certain users getting a 404 image not found while others will be able to see it.

You can also have a look at EBS volumes in order to try to achieve persistent storage with elastic beanstalk:  https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/

Comment: I see, so my only choice now is to use S3 bucket then :(
Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Its not ur only choice but I think its the most efficient way to do it. You can also create a mount on your ec2 which does not get deleted everytime you deploy. But than you have to make sure to sync all ec2 instances when a change is made in that mount

Comment: I somewhat agree that s3 is the most efficient way to do it., but I would still like to hear more about creating a mount on ec2 as another solution

Comment: Have a look at EBS volumes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html first and https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/ in order to try and have persistent storage with elastic beanstalk